# List.Contains() does not behave as expected

Tags: c#

I have created a function to check what software a client system has installed on it, then sending the information to the server it checks to see if the software is still on the system/database... Or at least that's what I want the function to do.

The current function code I have:

```
public void checkDeadPurposes()
{
    List<string> dbPurposes = new List<string>();
    List<string> syPurposes = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT machinePurpose FROM visualpurposes";
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            dbPurposes.Add(reader["machinePurpose"].ToString());
        }

        reader.Close();
    } catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    try
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in  purposes)
        {
            syPurposes.Add(kvp.Value);
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach(string sy in syPurposes)
        {
            if(dbPurposes.Contains(sy))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Purpose Found");
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Purpose Not Found");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n>>> System Purposes: " + string.Join(",", syPurposes.ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine(">>> Database Purposes: " + string.Join(",", dbPurposes.ToArray()) + "\n");
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

And it outputs:

[image: Output of function]

As you can see by the output, there should be an output for "one found" and "one not found", but it doesn't seem to respond when something isn't found.

Why is this? How can I fixed this?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError but the output shows that `syPurposes` isn't empty, it has `Visual Studio` in it.

Comment: This code is really hard to follow and incomplete. What is `purposes` and where is it filled?

Comment: The code works as expected. It loops through the `syPurposes`, and the single item there is reported as found in the `dbPurposes`. There is no item in the `syPurposes` that is not found in `dbPurposes`.

Comment: Agree with CodeCaster, where this comes from? KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in  purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one item in System Purposes.

This works as expected.

Are you sure you don't want to be iterating over Database purposes instead?

```
 foreach(string db in dbPurposes)
    {
        if(syPurposes.Contains(db))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Purpose Found");
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Purpose Not Found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Correct, That does work. But why doesn't it work the other way around?

Comment: Because there is only one item in syPurposes.  You only iterate the loop once.

Comment: Probably you need to intersect both Lists to get all hits. Iterating over dbPurposes might have the same problem if that list is the shorter one when using different input values.